# Laravel update column object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table, table name is bookings and here have a column e_service. this column i direct fetch data by id and save all data in e_service field how, can i update this e_service data like

```
    $booking = Booking::find($id);
    $booking->e_service->price = $request->price;
    $booking->e_service->discount_price = $request->discount_price;
    $booking->save();
```

table data return looks like below

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "e_provider":"{"id":11,"price":"5.55","discount_price":"4.55","mobile_number":"307.607.7472"}",
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the column type for `e_service`?

Comment: e_service = e_provider suppose, its a casts field, column type is longText

Comment: protected $casts = [
        'e_provider' => EProvider::class,
        'e_service' => EService::class,
    ];

Comment: Under e_service column have {"id":1,"name":{"en":"Deck Cleaning \/ Sealing"},"price":"37.56","discount_price":"32","price_unit":"hourly","quantity_unit":null,"duration":"5:00","enable_booking":false}

Comment: I want to update this price and discount price

Comment: So your `e_service` column is `json`? Why not store this information in a related table and make use of relationships?

Comment: This is not my project, i am customizing this project. I am thinking like you

Comment: As your column is json type  first  use json_decode() to decode the existing value like  $e_service[] = json_decode( $booking->e_service)   now use  array index to change the value of $e_servide[]. hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

Replace what you currently have with the following:

```
$booking = Booking::findOrFail($id);

$e_service = array_replace(json_decode($booking->e_service, true), [
    'price' => $request->price,
    'discount_price' => $request->discount_price,
]);

$booking->update([
    'e_service' => json_encode($e_service)
]);
```

Here we find the `Booking` in question before extracting the `e_service` field and decoding it from `JSON` to an `associative array`. Then use `array_replace` to update only the elements that are present in the `$request` so that we don't delete existing elements. Then we encode the new array before updating the `Booking`.